# Batch print line until string found

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a batch script that generates a file with the following structure (example)

```
123|etc|etc
345|etc|etc
678|etc|etc
```

I want my script to print out what it finds in each line, until it finds a |, so in this example i would want it to print:

123

345

678, and so on.

I've tried findstr /V with the | but it completely ignores the line (as the command states it will)

Any idea how could i turn this around?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the exact code you tried! Also take a look at [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html): `for /F "usebackq delims=|" %I in ("D:\path\to\your\file.txt") do echo %I` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Comment: `FINDSTR` is not a stream editor like `SED`.

Comment: thanks @aschipfl this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=|" %%a in ("test.txt") do (
      echo %%a )

      pause
```

This is looping through a file (test.txt) in the same directory as the batch script. I tell it to only use 1 token with a pipe delimiter then we just print out %%a which has the value of your first column of data.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning: this removes empty lines and lines starting with a `;`. And you could remove `tokens=1` since that's the default anyway

Comment: TBF @Stephan, a line which is empty doesn't have anything preceding a specific character! For any lines beginning with a semicolon, the simplest fix is to match the delimiter to the end of line character: `@For /F "UseBackEOL=|Delims=|" %%A In ("my file.ext")Do @Echo(%%A`